# all the layers are gone and i only have one named background with a lock

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I start by saying that I am new in the world of Photoshop. I was making some changes to a gif, I had finished making some changes, and I was going to continue the next day, so I saved and turned off the PC.

The next day I opened my file, and all the levels are gone, except one called “background”, does anyone know what happened? And the most important, what can I do?

Comment: What file format did you save it as? Image formats have different set of things they support. Like how `gifs` can be animated, but most other formats can't. Or how `png` can have transparency & translucency, but `gif` only supports transparency and `jpg` doesn't support either. — When you convert image to another file format, it will drop off any features not supported by it and not that many formats support layers. — Gifs actually don't support layers, but PS converts frames to layers.

Comment: Ideally in any application, you should save the file twice: first in the application's own format to retain editability if necessary (in PS it's `.psd`) and also a second time in the output format (`.gif` in your case). If you didn't save it as a `psd` or even a `gif`, there likely isn't anything that can be done. — Even if you did save it as `gif`, it is possible you saved it as a static file with no animation. In any case, the fact that you don't see any frames with a single background layer suggests it's now one flat image file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this happens since *GIF* does not support layers. Essentially you always want to save a *PSD* file for everything as a working copy then use export to publish the format you want.*

Theres nothing you can do. Data is lost. Put this down as a learning experience and move on with your life.

<sub>* this is not just a Photoshop thing. Similar things happen in most software. If you dont save in a native formats all bets are off.</sub>